# make C# installation file with network sql db or local sql db that choose by installer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express, advanced-installer, local-network

I want to make an installation file for my C# project
and by user selection they can connect to local database or connect to another computer db on local network

can I do that with "advanced installer"?
if not what can I do?!!!

Comment: Why is that an installation option? It sounds like a configuration option when the user is using the application.

Comment: my app must run on network for using by multiple users
I don't no what should I do!

Comment: Could create an administration utility to set options like that for multiple users.  Have advanced installer autolaunch that at the end of your installation.